# Error when running di compile after upgrade from 2.2.9 to 2.3.2 (TEMANDO)

Tags: module, fatal-error, magento-upgrade, setup-di-compile

I've tried disabling the temando module but i'm still getting the error.

```
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 74.0 MiB
Fatal error: Declaration of Temando\Shipping\Webservice\Processor\OrderOperation\PickupLocationRatesProcessor::postProcess(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $rateRequest, Temando\Shipping\Model\OrderInterface $requestType, Temando\Shipping\Webservice\Response\Type\QualificationResponseType $responseType) must be compatible with Temando\Shipping\Webservice\Processor\OrderOperation\RatesProcessorInterface::postProcess(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $rateRequest, Temando\Shipping\Model\OrderInterface $requestType, Temando\Shipping\Webservice\Response\Type\OrderResponseTypeInterface $responseType) in /srv/public_html/vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Webservice/Processor/OrderOperation/PickupLocationRatesProcessor.php on line 27
```

As you can see it starts to run but then bombs out 14% into the compile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CD into the vendor folder.
2. rm -rf temando/
3. composer update
4. n98-magerun2 setup:upgrade
5. n98-magerun2 setup:di:compile
6. n98-magerun2 setup:static-content:deploy
7. n98-magerun2 setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB (Static deploy often requires you designate your language packs as well otherwise it may not deploy properly.)
8. n98-magerun2 cache:flush
9. n98-magerun2 cache:disable
10. n98-magerun2 cache:enable

Obv. if you don't have n98 tools installed then just run normal php bin/magento whatever.

Cheers! Hope that works for you.

Comment: composer update is need to run ?